# mySQL and PHP login page problems

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have been trying to make this login form. All the mySQL is correct and it is connecting to the database, log in details are there and are correct when inputting however I get an error from PHP and the message that my log in details are wrong. I'm new to PHP/mySQL so I don't really know what I am doing wrong!

[Code for the page that connects to the database.](http://pastebin.com/DQmF30JM)

> Error from PHP: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/bluecode/public_html/intranet/checklogin.php on line 22

The variables from the form are myusername and mypassword.

Thanks :)

```
<?php


// username and password sent from form
$username=stripslashes($_POST['myusername']);
$password=sha1(stripslashes($_POST['mypassword']));


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="bluecode_power"; // Mysql username
$password="bluecode123"; // Mysql password
$db_name="bluecode_login"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$id", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select databse");

$sql="SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE myusername=='$username' and mypassword=='$password'";

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($myusername == admin){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){



// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}

else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont think you can filter w/ == in sql

Comment: Please please please check out [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) rather than using the now depreciated mysql.

Comment: Hmmmmm, the admin just needs a username to login?

Comment: Yes, is that a problem? At the moment I am just trying to get it to work!!

Comment: Could be wrong but this seems like a premature _"dupehammer"_ was thrown. While the error messages are similar, the causes appear to be different.

Comment: @crablab You have to execute the query once you fix the error pointed out by _@Cups_ below. Before `$count=mysql_num_rows($result);` you need to have `$result = mysql_query($sql);`...

Comment: Ammended; now more errors! Warning: mysql() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/bluecode/public_html/intranet/checklogin.php on line 28

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/bluecode/public_html/intranet/checklogin.php on line 29

Comment: @crablab Apologies, I edited my above comment. Make sure the command you just added is `mysql_query()` not `mysql()`. That was a typo on my part.

Comment: Fixed the errors but still returns 'Wrong Username or Password' when it is actually correct!

Comment: @crablab Your question keeps changing. Someone points a problem, then you fix your code and change the question. That's really doing a disservice to people who are trying to help you. The currently accepted answer for instance, points out a problem that is not in your question anymore. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: How is that a disservice to them? They help me, I then fix the problem. If anything it is a credit to them as their answer works!

Comment: @crablab What you've got here is a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: Fair point. I just don't know what the problem is! I will post a new and narrower question and not change it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL does not check for values using ==, use just one=

```
...where password='the secret'
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks: hasn't fixed the issue though. :(

Comment: ok, i'll take another look, ppl prefer you paste your code here tho, you could have left some of it out and still linked back to the pastebin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here! I think I have changed it now!

Comment: check your example (where you are learning from) again, the code you posted does not send the $sql statement into the db, to get the $result.

Comment: I had look at another question and changed some of the code (updated above) I got the error "Unknown column 'myusername' in 'where clause'"

Comment: ^^^I fixed that error; it was a variable problem (looking for a non existent column). Now it just tells me my credentials are wrong even though they are right!

Comment: how can you prove your credentials are correct? also, admin should be quoted  ... if($myusername == 'admin') you are checking for the string 'admin'.

Comment: I'm checking that the username and password in the form exist in the database. It works for admin now. But not for any other user.